# QScrollArea widget is not expanding with a Flowlayout

Tags: c++, qt, flowlayout, qscrollarea

I have a ui with a `QScrollArea` Widget. The `QScrollArea` uses a [Flowlayout](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/layouts-flowlayout.html). My problem is when I add widgets to my layout the scroll area begins to scroll and does not expand when it has room to expand. I  want the scroll area to expand to its limit before the scroll bar appears first.

How can I get the scroll area to expand before the scroll bar appears?

Comment: What does the layout look like for the widget that the QScrollArea is sitting in? Is there a layout?

Comment: @suslik The `QScrollArea` sits in a `QFrame` Widget.

Answer (score 7):

can you try doing `setWidgetResizable(true)` for your `QScrollArea`

```
ScrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Ensure that the size policy of the scroll area itself is Expanding.
2. Set the "stretch" values of the size policy of the scroll area to a value greater than that of the other widgets in the same layout.  Ie:

   ```
   QSizePolicy policy = pScrollArea->sizePolicy()

   policy.setVerticalStretch(1);
   policy.setHorizontalStretch(1);
   ```

   This assumes that the siblings of the scroll area (if any) have a stretch value of 0 (the default).
3. Subclass the scroll area and override the `sizeHint()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried 1 and 2 and will work on 3 shortly.